# Connecting to remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2005, the SQL Server instance name is `SOSO`, the machine name is `HERO`, I tried to connect from another computer using SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Server name: HERO\SOSO
Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

But I didn't succeed.

SQL Server is enabled to be connected remotely.

So what is the problem?

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: this is the error message:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: Any firewall in the middle? Perhaps you can't access SQL Server Port. If no "pshysical" firewall, you can try disabling the windows firewalls on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication uses the Active directory user from the connecting machine to authenticate with the database. Does it have the right permissions to access the database? Maybe try authenticating with a SQL Server database user first. Maybe you've created a SA user on installation, try connecting with that.

But as the other replies also tell, first check network / firewall connection and please provide us with the error message.

Comment: this is the error message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: yes there is a SA user, but I don't have it's password, I defined a new user called sam, and tried connecting using sql server authentication, but also didn't succeed! the same error

Comment: The error you are getting indicates there is a problem connecting to your DB server physically. Did you test the firewall / connection issues? If using TCP, port 1433 should be accessible. Is the SQL Server configured to allow remote connections?